# no Backend Counters beresp_bodybytes in varnishstat if option set beresp.do_gzip = true;

Tags: varnish

if i use the option "set beresp.do_gzip = true;" in "vcl_backend_response", I no longer have the value of Backend Counters beresp_bodybytes in varnishstat.

```
# with option: varnishstat -1|grep VBE.boot.front_fd.be 
VBE.boot.front_fd.bereq_hdrbytes                         71549599706     51664.65 Request header bytes
VBE.boot.front_fd.bereq_bodybytes                         2573041705      1857.95 Request body bytes
VBE.boot.front_fd.beresp_hdrbytes                        22571311577     16298.33 Response header bytes
VBE.boot.front_fd.beresp_bodybytes                                 0         0.00 Response body bytes
```

```
# with option: varnishstat -1|grep VBE.boot.front_fd.be
VBE.nogzip.front_fd.bereq_hdrbytes                           465977613       336.55 Request header bytes
VBE.nogzip.front_fd.bereq_bodybytes                           19200499        13.87 Request body bytes
VBE.nogzip.front_fd.beresp_hdrbytes                          139707046       100.90 Response header bytes
VBE.nogzip.front_fd.beresp_bodybytes                        6289803486      4542.72 Response body bytes
```

Comment: And what is the question? See: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: we are going to at least need a Varnish version to debug here, if you could also paste your VCL this would help too

Comment: I opened a ticket at varnish everything is inside.https://github.com/varnishcache/varnish-cache/issues/3354#issuecomment-646009658